# How to get selected option value?

Tags: angular, angular7

I use this code in template of component:

```
 <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedInvoice">
          <option>{{ "select" | translate }}</option>
          <option *ngFor="let item of invoices" [value]="item.AC_id"
            >{{ item.AC_code }} - {{ item.AC_name }}</option
          ></select
        >
```

Below I tried to show selected value:

```
{{selectedInvoice}}
```

It returns nothing always.

Component is:

```
export class SelectInvoiceDialog {
  public selectedInvoice: number;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the relevant code (e.g. the declaration of `selectedInvoice` and `invoices`)?

Comment: Sure, I have added to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does the `invoices` array look? Does it have `AC_id` as a property in its' objects? Your code looks fine, my guess would be that you typed `AC_id` by mistake and you actually where looking for `[value]="item.AC_code"`?

Comment: Yes, it is array, yes I have

Comment: Array is: `[ { "AC_id": 130, "AC_code": "1000", "AC_name": "Qeyri-maddi aktivlər - Amortizasiya", "AC_fname": "sdfdsfds", "AC_type": 0, "AC_group": 0, "enterprise_id": 1, "created_at": "2019-05-12 15:41:31", "parent_id": 0 } ] `